# Magento2 MSI v2.3.5 and up: What does "Synchronize with Catalog" do exactly?

Tags: magento2, stock, msi

We are seeing a new option in v2.3.5 "Synchronize with Catalog" and can read about it here. https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/configuration/catalog/inventory.html

But what does it do exactly? The explanation is ambiguous

*Synchronize with Catalog: When set to Yes, inventory data is adjusted according to the catalog changes (such as product removals, product SKU changes, and product type changes) and keeps consistency between inventory and catalog. Options: Yes / No*

**Question**: Magento2 MSI v2.3.5 and up: What does "Synchronize with Catalog" do exactly?

What are the suggested values for a normal shop using MSI? It defaults to NO when I would expect YES

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Magento Inventory keeps track of product stocks in the `\Magento\Inventory\Model\SourceItem` entity.
With "Synchronize with Catalog" enabled, it keeps these entities' updated via plugins on `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product::save`, `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product::delete` and more.

With "Synchronize with Catalog" disabled, Inventory SourceItems are only kept updated via Message Queues (that might be run by your cron).

Comment: So is it recommended or not?

Comment: It depends on your business case. With Sync enabled, stock will be synchronized "just-in-time" and uses CPU and IO at this time. With Sync disabled, those updates can be postponed until the next cron run (if you use the MySQL adapter).
I'd say: try the different modes on your staging environment and see what works best for your store.